# LED driver circuit works only when I touch it with my finger

Tags: capacitance, led-driver, touch

I'm trying to convert an E14 RGB LED bulb to be able to power it from a lithium battery. Inside the bulb are 2 PCBs - a transformer and a LED driver - which are connected by 3 wires. Black and red are DC ground and positive, white is for something else.

When I apply DC voltage to the driver board it works only while I'm touching the white wire with a finger. I tried to connect this wire to positive or to ground directly and via a capacitor - nothing seems to work.

On the transformer PCB this white wire is connected to one of the mains terminals via a 1 μF capacitor. On the driver board it is connected to ground via a 6.8 nF capacitor.

Maybe somebody here knows what this third wire is for, and what circuitry could possibly replace my finger?

[image: rgb bulb]

[image: transformer pcb]

[image: led driver pcb]

Comment: I don't know much of the circuit there.
I wish you can get the diagram of the circuit it will be better.
But what I want you to try is, connect a resistor on the white with and connect the other terminal of the resistor to the positive wire and see if it's going to work. If not, then remove it from the positive and connect it to ground. Show us the results.
Resistor should be between 1k upwards.
Test it and show the results.

Comment: Can you show us schematics? Without some kind of schematics, any answer would be little more than a guess.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have schematics.

Comment: @Artur Then start working on reverse engineering and drawing some schematics, because I don't think this is answerable without a better understanding of what the circuit does.

Comment: It would be interesting if that white wire was intended to pick up the 60 Hz of the powerline and your finger gave it enough AC hum to make it happen

Comment: I was thinking so too. Tried to connect sinal generator set to 50hz on the smartphone to white wire via the headphones jack. No change besides that circuit works when I touch the smartphone.

Comment: I've seen such PSU's in LED lamps where the main switching supply is a current regulator for the LED's and the logic IC's are supplied by capacitive dropper. Perhaps that's what the white wire is for? What's on the backside of the PSU board?